# jQuery won't return expected .text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and I have an html file with this div element.

```
<div id="test div">Test Text</div>
```

and this div element.

```
<div id="dump contents"></div>
```

In my javascript file, I have this:

```
var testvariable = $("#test div").text();
$("#dump contents").html(testvariable);
```

But no matter what I do, nothing happens :(

Any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not use space character in IDs.

Comment: IDs with spaces are invalid. And spaces inside a selector constitute the *descendant selector*: http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the `id` attribute should be without spaces

```
<div id="test-div">Test Text</div>
```

and

```
<div id="dump-contents"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var testvariable = $("#test-div").text();
$("#dump-contents").html(testvariable);
```

from [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.